# Dynamics CRM REST oData endpoint support for All and Any

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Just wondering if current REST endpoint (2013) supports Any or All for filtering based on child entity:

```
http://localhost/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$select=Name&$expand=lead_parent_account&$filter=lead_parent_account/any(x:x.City eq '')
```

Comes back with:
No property 'any' exists in type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' at position 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OData endpoint only returns entities, you cannot perform boolean queries such as `IEnumerable<T>.Any()`/`.All()`<sup>1</sup>.

Everything needs to start from data: a query similar to yours to grab the relevant entities might look like this:

```
/AccountSet?$select=Name&$expand=lead_parent_account&$filter=lead_parent_account/City eq ''
```

If you get a non-empty set of results, then the equivalent `.Any()` is `true`.

Checking `.All()` is nasty: the closest way I can think of would be checking if the query has returned all records from `AccountSet` (gonna take a while if you have thousands of records, also remember that results are capped at capped at 5000 per query, and paged if there are more).

(<sup>1</sup>: Of course, if one performs a `QueryExpression` in code, the results can be LINQ-ed at will, since you're no longer relying on the quite limited LINQtoCRM query provider, but it's not very relevant here)